# Uploading multiple image files with multer from different input fields

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am not able to upload two images from two different input tags using Multer.

This is the code of the html form

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h1>Upload Image 1</h1>
    <input name="photo1" type="file" />
    <img id="output_image" />

    <h1>Upload Image 2</h1>
    <input name="photo2" type="file" />
    <img id="output_image1" />
  
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

This is the code of the nodejs file

```
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/upload', upload.fields([
    { name: 'photo1', maxCount: 1},
    { name: 'photo2', maxCount: 1}
]), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    next();
});
```

But the request object is always undefined.
I tried following the documentation but it didn't solve this issue.

Previously I tried uploading a single file which did work out. For that I removed the below part of the form

```
<h1>Upload Image 2</h1>
<input name="photo2" type="file" />
<img id="output_image1" />
```

And this was the nodejs file same as the one on the documentation

```
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/upload', upload.single('photo1'), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    next();
});
```

I am not able to find the mistake here. Is it not possible to take two images from different input fields using multer? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Your Multer and HTML form setup is right. When using  Multer `upload.fields()` use `req.files['photo1'][0]` not `req.file` to access the uploaded files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any of the following approaches

1. Will this help you `.any()`
   **Accepts all files that comes over the wire. An array of files will be stored in req.files.**

WARNING: Make sure that you always handle the files that a user uploads. Never add multer as a global middleware since a malicious user could upload files to a route that you didn't anticipate. Only use this function on routes where you are handling the uploaded files.

i am saying this from [here][1].

2. or  for multiple files use this

Instead of `upload.single('image')` you want to do `upload.array('image')`, and then look at `req.files instead of req.file.`

3)

```
app.post("/upload", function(req, res, fields) {

  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "public/data/",
    filename: function(req, file, cb){
      crypto.randomBytes(20, (err, buf) => {
        cb(null, buf.toString("hex") + path.extname(file.originalname))
      })
    }
  });

  const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
  }).fields([{name: "pp"}, {name: "banner"}]);

  upload(req, res, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });

});
```

for more explanation https://codingstatus.com/upload-multiple-files-using-multer-in-node-js-and-express/

Comment: I tried this approach before switching to upload.fields() but even that didn't work.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check if that works for you.

Comment: I want to upload multiple files from multiple input fields because i want to handle them differently on the html side which i think is not possible by .arrays() as it takes multiple files from the same input field